# can we add properties on request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to use single validate for birthday year, birth month, birth day as birthday for registration in laravel 5.4 here is my code

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // here i want to add bithday input on reqeust but nothing happen
    $request->birthday = implode('-', array(
            $request->birth_year,
            $request->birth_month,
            $request->birth_date
        ));

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'User successfully registered');
}
```

nothing happen with that code, I can validate those 1 by 1 using date_format. the problem is what if the user select February and day is 31

Comment: another option i can use is a single input but 3 select field is more user friendly

Comment: `$request->merge(['birthday' => 'Your Value']);` However, you're doing it a bit extended here, with Laravel 5.4 you can [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#creating-form-requests) which lets you split validation from controller into a separate file. Anyway, to inject a value into `$request`, you'd use `$request->merge()` method.

Comment: @white-comet You could use a date picker, which would completely bypass this issue

Comment: @Mjh if its the only way, i know laracst have free video for Form request thanks man i'll try it

Comment: @adamj - it wouldn't. Even if you implement a date picker, you can still sent whatever you want to the server.

Comment: @adamj not user friendly what coz its display month 1 by 1 what if the year is 1970's btw the date picker i used on other page like schedule page is jquery ui but if you have any datepicker w/c is more user firendly just tell  me thanks

Comment: btw mjh just merge can do, no need for form request but i got the idea first on you thanks man

Comment: @Mjh It would, because you can disable the input so no one can enter anything manually.

Comment: @white-comet Not user friendly? A date picker? Seriously?

Comment: @mjh can you jump from 2017 to 1970 on jquery-ui datepicker in 20 sec?

Comment: @adamj you think that user can't send arbitrary data to web server *without* UI on your website or what? You can send _anything_ you want, sticking a datepicker doesn't mean that your server handles user input well. Please, research HTTP protocol and how it works. It's so trivial to do this with any browser these days, and if you leave a hole in your site because you're lazy - that's up to you.

Comment: @white-comet - I can send whatever I want. Right click on input box > inspect element, change value manually, submit the form. Now I can send whatever I want and if you don't handle it on server properly - you're in for a world of trouble.

Comment: @Mjh Mate, you're a funny one. Your average joe isn't going to wander in there to specifically re-enable the input to enter gibberish. What's funnier , you wasting your time sending the date as 3 different inputs rather than a single input that you could have with a date picker and then check that if it's a valid date... but hey what ever floats your boat

Comment: @adamj is it for mj or for me? i choose 3 dropdown for UX, you think why facebook choose 3 dropdown for birthday if datepicker gave user more good UX

Comment: @adamj adding a date picker to UI does not solve the problem of parsing and validating user input. There are no simpler words that I can use to highlight that. You want to promote bad coding practices - excellent, more work for me. Now, take whatever you want from my comment, internet arguments can never be settled because your starting assumption is that you can't be wrong. I don't plan to continue this further, let's end it with this.

Comment: @Mjh sorry man i though you are adamj who promote datepicker for birthday, i know user can manipulate the DOM just just inspect element, sorry for wrong reply, i'm on your side

Comment: @white-comet - it's fine, no worries :) I can tell that we managed to help you, but sometimes we go out of our way and start arguing over silly things. Everything's fine, have a nice day! You too adamj!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L269), you can use the `merge` method.

```
$request->merge(['birthday' => implode('-', [
    $request->birth_year,
    $request->birth_month,
    $request->birth_date
])]);
```

Comment: oh i do not need to use form request, thanks you @Patrick Reck and Mjh

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. For example, you can use `add()` method to add data to the `Request` object:

```
$request->request->add(['birthday', implode('-', [
        $request->birth_year,
        $request->birth_month,
        $request->birth_date
    )]);
```

But here, I'd just do something like this:

```
$data = $request->all();

$data['birthday'] = implode('-', [
        $request->birth_year,
        $request->birth_month,
        $request->birth_date
    ]);

$this->validator($data)->validate();

event(new Registered($user = $this->create($data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

my way is:

```
$all = $request->all();
$year = $all['birth_year'];
$month = $all['birth_month'];
$day = $all['birth_date'];

 // Create Carbon date
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
// $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->birth_year.'-'.$request->birth_month.'-'.$request->birth_date); another way

//add new [birthday] input
$request->request->add(['birthday' => $date->format('Y-m-d')]); 

$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'birthday' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|before:today',// validate birth day
]);
```

**Hope this helps someone**